# Animate a div to reveal absolutely positioned content using CSS and/or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a container which I'd like to expand to reveal content that is absolutely positioned to the bottom right corner once the container is fully expanded.

Expanding a container is pretty simple using CSS.

```
@keyframes test-grow {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30rem;
  }  
}

.test {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  animation: test-grow 5s forwards;
}
```

The tricky part is revealing the content within it. Using simple absolute positioning isn't working as the content fixes to the bottom right of the container regardless of it's size, so it moves with the corner of the container as it grows.

Here's a quick GIF example of what I'd like to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTOH.jpg but my reveal will be smooth from corner to corner.

I've a pen here: http://codepen.io/abbasinho/pen/QyrZOm?editors=1100 that shows the container animation. But you'll see my issue with the content.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boom. There ya go

```
.test {
  position: relative;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: rgba(white, 0.5);
  animation: test-grow 5s forwards;
  overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top:  18rem;
  left: 28rem;
}
```

Comment: The reason this works, by the way, is because the top & left of the container are static, so you can position your text based off of those reference points and your text will stay in the same position during the course of the animation.

Comment: Exactly the right way to go about it, if you ask me! :)

Comment: @mhodges Great solution - i've got it working really well. An extension of the issue would be to get it working with percentage values. But I think that's a solution for another day :)